# I am trying to center align my fig caption underneath my picture

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code for the image.

```css
.image1
{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="T-shirt colors" class="image1">
  <figcaption>Choose from are variety of t-shirt colors</figcaption>
</figure>
```

How do I get my text to center up below the image?

Answer (score 2):

You can center align the text of `figcaption` as

```
figcaption{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.image1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="T-shirt colors" class="image1">
  <figcaption>Choose from are variety of t-shirt colors</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by seting the `text-align` property on `figcaption` to `center` like so:

```css
figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in future, you may want to add in a little code.io for us to play around with. we dont know how your parent box looks like, or the css of your parents box.

you may want to check this out

http://howtocenterincss.com/

it is a very useful cheat tool, i think

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `text-align: center;` to your figcaption tag.